# I Got the Like Button Code from Facebook, but it Doesn't Appear

Tags: html, facebook

I'm all about HTML Web Design and Android App Building, so when I think about trying to get users, I refer to my Facebook Page and getting the Like button code from Facebook Developers, but when I inserted the code, it doesn't show!

```
<body>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=347485521975925";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Warriors-of-Atlantis/512072738825326" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="lucida grande" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

Comment: works as is in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2S6rn/

Comment: It doesn't seem to work and I'm previewing in Chrome so IDK if Chrome is set up for HTML5 like Facebook says this code is for

Answer (score 0):

I may be using a slightly outdated version of the like box, but my working code looks just a little bit different.  Try putting < div id="fb-root">< /div> right before the opening script tag.

Comment: I realized that this works `iframe 
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FWarriors-of-Atlantis%2F512072738825326&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;action=like&amp;height=80&amp;appId=347485521975925" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`